# Update key in Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a few NSDictionaries inside of an NSArray.  I want to modify a BOOL inside one of the dictionaries so that the whole array will have that change (it loads a tableview).

I have this code but it doesn't change the BOOL.  I feel like I need to remove the `mutableCopy` to work, but then it crashes...

```
    NSLog(@"before: %@", self.currentScopeArray);
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"enabledByDefault"];
    } else {    
        if (!(self.currentScopeArray.count < 2)) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [[[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row]mutableCopy] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"enabledByDefault"];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"after: %@", self.currentScopeArray);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a bunch of NSDictionary to a NSArray. I would suggest that you

- Make the NSArray into a NSMutableArray
- Make the NSDictionary into an NSMutableDictionary

Why? because you already need to modify values in the Dictionary. And, chances are that you may *also* want to add/remove dictionaries from the array. Once you have made them mutable, you can then do this:

```
   [[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"enabledByDefault"];
```

and

```
[[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"enabledByDefault"];
```

Another problem with With your current implementation is that you are operating on the *mutable copy* and **not** on the original dictionary. The copy is modified, the original is not.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a mutable copy of the object then it'll be exactly that, a copy. If you want to mutate the object that is already inside `currentScopeArray` then either you need to have mutable objects in the array already, or you need to get a mutable copy, mutate it and then replace the original object.

I would suggest the former to be honest. So you would create your `currentScopeArray` by adding `NSMutableDictionary`s to it and then just replace this line:

```
[[[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row]mutableCopy] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"enabledByDefault"];
```

with this:

```
[[self.currentScopeArray objectAtIndex:iIndexPath.row] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"enabledByDefault"];
```

Comment: So you removed `mutableCopy` from that line, but what else do I need to do? The app crashes if thats all I do.

Comment: You need your dictionaries in that array to be `NSMutableDictionary`s. How are you creating the array in the first place?